# Counting how many pairs of numbers in Python list

Tags: python-3.x

I searched around and found how to return how many pairs of same value in list. As an example:
x = [10,10,20,30,20] => It should return 2 because we have 2 pairs of same value each: (10,10) and (20,20).
What is confusing me and do not understand, why the function below is returning result + 1? which leads to wrong output.
Output should be 2 but I have 3!! Thank you very much.

```
x = [20, 30, 20, 30, 20, 40, 30]
freq = {} 
count = 0 
for item in x: 
  if (item in freq): 
     freq[item] += 1
  else:
    freq[item] = 1
for key, value in freq.items(): 
    count+=value/2 
print("Pairs : ",int(count))
```

Comment: How do you count overlapping pairs. Does `[1, 1, 1]` contain one pair, or three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below line of code is not what you are looking for :

```
set(ar).intersection(mylist)
```

It just prints out the number of unique elements in your list.

You could do something like this :

```
freq = {}
count = 0 
for item in x: 
    if (item in freq): 
        freq[item] += 1
    else: 
        freq[item] = 1

for key, value in freq.items(): 
    count+=value/2
print("Pairs : ",count)
```

Comment: they are giving us much advanced functions to solve in comparison with what we are learning. this is what i came to so far. Do you have any suggestions please. thank you very much.

Comment: thank you very much for your support but its giving me a result of 3.5 while it should be 3. do i have to delete the float ? sorry for bothering you

Comment: i got it bro  i have just to add int(count) in last line. thank you very much. respect.

Comment: Use `value // 2`. That does floor division, rather than creating a floating point value you need to convert afterwards.